# C++ use of deleted function error with conditional intiailization

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to conditionally initialize the object ClassB based on some condition:

**Main.cpp**

```
ClassB r;
if (mycond) {
    r = ClassB(3);
}
else {
    r = ClassB(2);
}
```

I have some class like this:

**ClassA.hpp**

```
class ClassA {

    private:
        const int hahaha = 3;
    public:
        ClassA () {};
};
```

**ClassB.hpp**

```
class ClassB: private ClassA {

    private:
        int jajaja;
    public:
        ClassB () {};
        ClassB (int);

};
```

**ClassB.cpp**

```
ClassB::ClassB() { }

ClassB::ClassB(int a) { 
    jajaja = a
}
```

However I am getting the same error over and over. 
I have browser similar questions and they all give the same general answer: you need an empty constructor. I have an empty constructor, but I am still getting this error.

```
Main.cpp: error: use of deleted function ‘ClassB& ClassB::operator=(ClassB&&)’
       r = ClassB(3);
         ^
In file included from Main.cpp:
ClassB.hpp: note: ‘ClassB& ClassB::operator=(ClassB&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class ClassB: private ClassA {
   ^
ClassB.hpp: error: use of deleted function ‘ClassA& ClassA::operator=(ClassA&&)’
In file included from ClassB.hpp:,
             from Main.cpp:
Data_Analysis.hpp: note: ‘ClassA& ClassA::operator=(ClassA&&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class ClassA {
   ^
ClassA.hpp: error: non-static const member ‘const int ClassA::’, can’t use default assignment operator
```

If I do not use a conditional initialization, aka "ClassB r (3);", everything complies and runs smoothly.

Comment: With the code you show you should not even be able to create an instance of `ClassB` since its constructors are private. Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Don't ever use `const` data members, it prevents assignment. Instead, make the object itself `const`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "condition initialization". You are not initializing anything in the condition. You are assigning to an existing instance which was already initialized. And because your class has a `const` class member, its default assignment operator has been deleted, because you can't assign to something that's `const`, by definition. You will need to implement your own assignment operator, in your class with the `const` class member.

Answer (score 0):

```
const int hahaha = 3;
```

Is ultimately where your problem is.  I'll try to break it down for you axiomatically

**Axiom 1**

Whenever you do something like

```
obj1 = obj2;  // they are of the same type
```

Under the hood, obj1's *copy assignment operator* (operator=) will be called.

**Axiom 2**

If possible (and that's a big if in your case), the compiler will try to generate a default operator= for you.  The default operator would do a copy of all members and all the inherited members.  The generated code would try to look something like this in your case

```
ClassB& operator=(const ClassB& other)
{
  jajaja = other.jajaja;
  hahaha = other.hahaha; // ClassA's operator=
  return *this;
}
```

If for some reason this operation is not possible, the default operator will be marked "deleted"

**Axiom 3**

*const* members cannot be changed post-construction.

**Conclusion**

I hope you start to see what's wrong now.  When you try to do

```
r = ClassB(3 /*or 2, doesn't really matter*/);
```

This would cause the secret function operator= (in *r*) to be called.  The compiler knows this function would fail because

```
r.hahaha = other.hahaha;
```

will fail, due to r's *hahaha* being a const and can't be modified.

Comment: Ps. your compile error 
"ClassA.hpp: error: non-static const member ‘const int ClassA::’, can’t use default assignment operator"
is somehow missing one crucial information.  I'm pretty sure it meant to say "const int ClassA::hahaha".  Not sure what's up with that.